# TypeScript why use traditional classes instead of interfaces?

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, oop, interface

I can do this:

```
enum DogsKinds {
  Labrador,
  Aski
}

class Dog {
  name: string;
  kind: DogKinds;
  constructor() {}
}
```

And then init a dog object:

```
const dog = new Dog();
```

However I can do the same with interface:

```
interface Dog {
  name: string;
  kind: DogsKind;
}

const dog: Dog = {
  name: 'some name',
  kind: DogsKinds.Labrador
}
```

And get the same result - easier.

What are the differences, when to use interface and when to use classes, is there a best practice or rule of thumb?

It seems that interfaces are easier to work with, if I wrong please correct me.

Comment: You can also omit both entirely (like I prefer) when possible and use plain object literals and inferred types.

Comment: But I cannot reuse it later on

Comment: @Raz Well your demo code does not show examples of reuse either. Try adding that and the advantage of constructors should become more obvious

Comment: Btw you'll want to fix the "*Property 'name' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor. Property 'kind' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.*" errors that the compiler spews out

Comment: Notice that in TypeScript, every `class` declaration does both declare an interface (a type) and define a `class` object.

Answer (score 0):

I think one important difference is finding out at runtime which *kind of object* you are dealing with when using **inheritance**.

With classes you can use the `instanceof` operator:

```
if (animal instanceof Dog) { /* ... */ }
```

When you are just using plain objects with TypeScript you will have to supply an additional property to differentiate the types during runtime.

```
type AnimalType = 'dog' | 'cat'

interface Dog extends Animal {
  type: 'dog'
  name: string;
  kind: DogsKind;
}

if (animal.type === 'dog') { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: No need for an additional property, you can just use duck typing with interfaces.